# Copy entire website to iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I've created a website for a client's salesforce to use in hospitals, where they can't use wifi to access the internet as it can interfere with sensitive medical equipment. The website uses HTML, CSS and Javascript and does not require any form of server to work, which is fine when run locally on a laptop. However, they now want to use iPads and I've been trawling the Net for a simple solution in which I could copy the entire site to an iPad, while maintaining the site's directory structure, and then launch it locally with the browser. Nothing that I've found seems to be able to do this, although it seems such a ridiculously straightforward thing.

The best I've been able to do is to email the zipped site to my iPod, and then use the FileManager app to unzip and run the site in its own browser. It's useable but not great (every time you tap something you get an overlay at the top of the page) and there's no way I can find of adding a shortcut to the desktop - is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Typically you'd use something like https://cordova.apache.org/ for this. If it handles HIPAA data and you're in the US, you should involve the hospital's legal department before storing such data on the iPads.

Comment: That doesn't look like the case here @ceejayoz.

Comment: Redesign your site so that it doesn't have an overlay when you tap on something...?

Comment: The overlay is part of the FileManager app, not the website. I have no control over it.

Comment: I've had a look at Cordova and it appears that - and I may be entirely wrong about this - the only way to get the website on to iPads is via the Store. I doubt my client would be happy with that, and it seems overkill for what I'm trying to do. Is there no way to just copy the site to an iPad and create a link on its desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into something like React Native which allows you to write javascript HTML applications and deploy them as native iOS and Android applications. It shouldn't require too much work to move it over enough to just compile it and run it as you do currently.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Answer (score 1):

Cordova to package it in to an app https://cordova.apache.org/

Comment: Looks like Cordova might be a better choice. From the documentation, it looks like React Native is probably going to take a lot more conversion to get the existing website operational again,

Comment: I agree, for something like this that does not require anything additional it is better just using Cordova.  I haven't looked into React, but most things like that end up being a shell on top of cordova anyways.

Comment: I haven't used either, but from the brief documentation it looks like React Native is unrelated to Cordova. React Native looks to be using javascript as the syntax that compiles a native objective-c/java app as opposed to native HTML/Javascript being wrapped in a native container